# Angular Filter string replace

Tags: angularjs, regex, filter, angular-filters

I created a filter in angular 1 and have some questions:

I have an string like this:

```
**StackExchange** is a website...
```

and the desired outcome would be:

```
<span class="title">StackExchange</span> is a website...
```

my filter looks like this:

```
.filter('makeSpan', function() {
  return function(input, all) {
    return (!!input) ? input.replace(/[*]{2}/, '<span class="title">')  : '';
  }
});
```

When Applying this filter I get StackExchange** is a website... My question is how can I do so I can target the other 2 **. Thanks.

Comment: Using html elements looks more like that you need a directive to me

Comment: if data wouldn't come from an API, you'd be right.

Answer (score 1):

If you HTML input is tag-free, you may "target" both the `**` pairs with:

```
return (!!input) ? input.replace(/\*{2}([^]*?)\*{2}/g, '<span class="title">$1</span>') : '';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qeJh3N/1)

- `\*{2}`  - `**`
- `([^]*?)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1`) capturing any 0+ chars, as few as possible up to the first...
- `\*{2}`  - `**`

Answer (score 0):

This actually seems to be working.

```
return (!!input) ? input.replace(/[*]{2}/, '<span class="title">').replace(/[*]{2}/, '</span>')  : '';
```

Comment: It seems you need `return (!!input) ? input.replace(/\*{2}([^]*?)\*{2}/g, '<span class="title">$1</span>')  : '';`